# How can I see what files are tracked within a newly created directory?

Tags: git, gitignore

I have created a new directory with a bunch of new files. Before I commit, I want to see if my `.gitignore` file is working correctly, eg: I want to see what files come up as changed/created if I run `git status`.

Of course, since my whole directory is new I only see:

```
Untracked files:

    MyNewProject/
```

How can I check what files are being tracked within that new directory?

Comment: `cd MyNewProject` and then `git status`. Doesn't it work?

Comment: @john, no it just indicates the parent directory is untracked (`Untracked Files: ./`)

Comment: What about `git status -v -uall` ? Forget about cd MyNewProject. :) Not sure but maybe you can even do `git status -v -v` (double -v)

Answer (score 0):

Did you freshly initialise git and then created `MyNewProject` folder?
    git init
    mkdir MyNewProject
    // add some files

or did you add `MyNewProject` inside a project that you've been already working on?

Like @john said, `git status -u` will do the work. The `mode` parameter defaults to `all` so if you haven't changed anything, `git status -u` will be the same as `git status -uall`. 
Here's [link](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status#git-status--ultmodegt) with detailed explanation.

Comment: I added MyNewProject inside a project I was already working on and that had several commits already.